# Can't style datepiker popup dialog

Tags: material-ui

I have a problem with customizing the datepicker [popup dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MO5L3.png)(For example change color of header). I can't style it by attribute style like textField by textFieldStyle. It doesn't have any class or id.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The only place you can currently override this is the theme:

```
import React from 'react';
import {cyan500} from 'material-ui/styles/colors';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme';
import MyAppRoot from './MyAppRoot';

const muiTheme = getMuiTheme({
  datePicker: {
    selectColor: cyan500,
  },
});

class Main extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={muiTheme}>
        <MyAppRoot />
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}

export default Main;
```

Comment: I think it should be ```datePicker: { selectColor: cyan500 }``` instead of palette..

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the latest version of Material-UI, things changed. `MuiThemeProvider`  and `getMuiTheme` are replaced by `createMuiTheme` and `ThemeProvider` respectively.

You can use like this:
`import { createMuiTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';`

Now Material-UI is using tree-shaking mechanism to avoid unnecessary bundles, so destructing is well to go.

To change the header, use something like this:

```
const muiTheme = createMuiTheme({
    overrides: {
        MuiPickersToolbar: {
            toolbar: { backgroundColor: 'var(--themeP)' }
        },

...
```