# Cannot style material-ui Date Picker OK/Cancel button

Tags: datepicker, styles, material-ui

I followed the steps in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37400648/cant-style-datepiker-popup-dialog) to change the background color material-ui --> [Date Picker](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/date-picker) dialog by changing the theme. Changing the theme changed background color but it did not change the color of the OK and CANCEL buttons.How to change the color of OK and CANCEL buttons?

Comment: The material-ui documentation says something about "dialogContainerStyle" can be used to Override the inline-styles of DatePickerDialog's Container element. But I do not know how to use that attribute.

Answer (score 9):

You have two options to customize the color of the OK and Cancel buttons.

1. (Easier) If you are okay with all flat buttons in your application using same, customized color you want to use on your Date Picker buttons, then you can simply add

   ```
   flatButton: {
       primaryTextColor: purple500, // Whatever color you want.
   }
   ```

   to the object you are passing into your `getMuiTheme()` call.
2. If you are only customizing the button colors in this situation, and want the other Flat Buttons in your application to take the theme's color, then you need to customize the `muiTheme` right before the `DatePicker` is used.

   So if we wanted to have all of our Flat Buttons to be `cyan500`, then we would set that at our main

   ```
   const mainMuiTheme = getMuiTheme({
       flatButton: { primaryTextColor: cyan500 }
   })

   const WrapperWithMainThemeProvider = (props) => {
       return (
           <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={mainMuiTheme}>
               <MyDatePicker />
           </MuiThemeProvider>
       )
   }
   ```

   Then if wanted the buttons in our `DatePicker` to be customized, then we do that in a custom component.

   ```
   class MyDatePicker extends React.class {
       render() {
           const muiTheme = getMuiTheme({
               ...this.context.muiTheme,
               flatButton: {
                   primaryTextColor: purple500,
               }
           })

           // Customize the muiTheme, and pass it down in a new MuiThemeProvider.
           // Only Flat Buttons that are children of this component 
           // will have the new color.
           return (
               <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={muiTheme}>
                   <DatePicker />
               </MuiThemeProvider>
           )
       }
   }

   MyDatePicker.contextTypes = {
       muiTheme: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Material-UI uses Flatbutton as default on datepicker or for any dialog. Which means the OK/CANCEL button you see on datepicker is nothing but a flatbutton. So to apply background color to OK/CANCEL button of Date picker you have to use color instead of primaryTextColor. The color attribute of flatbutton does change the button background color. Please find example below and [Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19iTX.png)

```
import DatePicker from 'material-ui/DatePicker';

const mainMuiTheme = getMuiTheme({
flatButton: { color: '#333' }
})

const WrapperWithMainThemeProvider = (props) => {
return (
    <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={mainMuiTheme}>
        <DatePicker
          floatingLabelText="Date Of Birth" 
          hintText="Select Date Of Birth" 
          container="inline" 
          locale="en-US" 
          firstDayOfWeek={0} 
          autoOk={true} 
          value={this.state.dob} 
          onChange={this.changeDateOfBirth} 
          defaultDate={this.state.dateYesterday}
      >
      </DatePicker>
    </MuiThemeProvider>
)
}
```

And below is what Material-UI expects muiTheme styles for FlatButton.

```
 flatButton: {
  color: transparent,
  buttonFilterColor: '#999999',
  disabledTextColor: fade(palette.textColor, 0.3),
  textColor: palette.textColor,
  primaryTextColor: palette.primary1Color,
  secondaryTextColor: palette.accent1Color,
  fontSize: typography.fontStyleButtonFontSize,
  fontWeight: typography.fontWeightMedium,
}
```

For more information about muiTheme styles of each material-UI component check the following link https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/src/styles/getMuiTheme.js

I tested this and it worked for me. Hope this answer helpful.

Comment: Where can I view all those DatePicker properties ?