# Change header color of Material-UI Date Picker

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, datepicker, material-ui

I added a Material-UI Date Picker in my React Single Page Application but I don't know how to change the header color.
I tried to change it from muiTheme pallete property but the header is the only color that remain the same:

```
 var muiTheme = getMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary1Color: '#135DAE',
    primary2Color: '#135DAE',
    primary3Color: '#135DAE',
    accent1Color: '#EF243A',
    accent2Color: '#135DAE',
    accent3Color: '#135DAE',
  },
  appBar: {
    height: 50,
  },
})
```

Here is the Date Picker's HTML code:

```
 <DatePicker
        hintText="Selected day"
        value={this.state.controlledDate.toDate()}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        autoOk
 />
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you have to specify the datepicker and header color as part of the muiTheme. The following is from [getMuiSource.js on Github](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/src/styles/getMuiTheme.js).

```
datePicker: {
      color: palette.primary1Color,
      textColor: palette.alternateTextColor,
      calendarTextColor: palette.textColor,
      selectColor: palette.primary2Color,
      selectTextColor: palette.alternateTextColor,
      calendarYearBackgroundColor: palette.canvasColor,
      headerColor: palette.pickerHeaderColor || palette.primary1Color,
    },
```

Also, see this [answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37414025/208079).

Comment: Hello can you please answer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53391633/material-ui-time-picker-header-text-color

Comment: how can I change the buttons action color?

Answer (score 1):

This is a good guide for changing DatePicker themes in material-ui https://material-ui-pickers.dev/guides/css-overrides

Answer (score -3):

Change primary2Color: '#135DAE',