# Material ui time picker header text color

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am integrating [material ui time picker](https://github.com/TeamWertarbyte/material-ui-time-picker)

I need to change the color of time

[image]

You can see in the image. I need to change the color of `11:30 pm`

I searched a lot but couldn't able do it.

Please help!!!

EDIT:

I tried this

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: '#efbb40'
    }
  },
  typography: {
    useNextVariants: true,
    suppressDeprecationWarnings: true
  }
})
```

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: @Dekel Updated the question

Comment: if you are open to use [@material-ui/pickers](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui-pickers), which seems to be the [recommended one](https://material-ui.com/components/pickers/#material-ui-pickers) and has a [broader usage](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui-pickers), you can [easily override the default color](https://next.material-ui-pickers.dev/guides/css-overrides#override-example)