# How to set the color of the clock (timePicker) with material-ui?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I tried to change the color of the clock of timeInput (`material-ui-time-picker`) for the material-ui, but it's not changing.

My code is :

```
<TimeInput
        style ={heure}
        mode='24h'
        value={heureDebut}
        onChange={this.handleheureDChange}
        autoOk={true} 
        cancelLabel=""
        okLabel=""
        placeholder=""
        disableUnderline={true}  
        endAdornment={
            <InputAdornment position="end" style={{opacity:'0.4', marginLeft:'92px'}}>
            <IconButton><i style={{fontSize:'18px'}} className="zmdi zmdi-alarm" /></IconButton>
            </InputAdornment>
        }
                      

/>
```

When I run it, I get :

[image]

But I want the color blue will be changed to `#0E6EB8`

How can I change it?

Answer (score 4):

So this is an old question but I was trying to do the same and got here hoping to find a solution.

Here is what I learned:

The only way I found to change the clock and calendar styles is to override the default theme.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-counter-demo-forked-tbc2z?file=/src/index.js:3702-3712) is a codeSandbox where I did my experiments.

Also, I posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63510150/style-material-ui-inputbase-with-date-time-pickers/63513180?noredirect=1#comment112328720_63513180) regarding this and there were some helpful comments.

It is a real pain to do this with material UI, specially since you need to find out how to override the theme on your own, using the inspector. Hopefully the things I figured out in the codeSandbox example are enough to help the next person.

**DISCLAIMER:** Sorry for all the unnecessary code in my example. I was trying different approaches.

Answer (score 1):

[Source](https://github.com/dmtrKovalenko/material-ui-pickers/issues/393#issuecomment-427460325)

```
import DateFnsUtils from "material-ui-pickers/utils/date-fns-utils";
import React from "react";
import MuiPickersUtilsProvider from "material-ui-pickers/utils/MuiPickersUtilsProvider";
import DatePicker from "material-ui-pickers/DatePicker";
import KeyboardArrowLeft from "@material-ui/icons/KeyboardArrowLeft";
import KeyboardArrowRight from "@material-ui/icons/KeyboardArrowRight";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const styles = theme => ({
  input: {
    color: "red"
  }
});

const Calendar = ({ classes, ...rest }) => (
  <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
    <DatePicker
      {...rest}
      leftArrowIcon={<KeyboardArrowLeft />}
      rightArrowIcon={<KeyboardArrowRight />}
      InputProps={{ className: classes.input }}
    />
  </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
);

Calendar.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default withStyles(styles)(Calendar);
```

Comment: This is just a copy of the code from the link above --

Comment: @AGR how can I integrate it, because I have a constuctor and class inside it, I have timepicker

Answer (score 0):

To change the color, you need to change the background color in css.
`.MuiPickersToolbar-toolbar-2295` is the class name. So change background color in this class.

[image]

Comment: can you share your sandbox please ?

Comment: Please inspect and find the class name and change the colour in corresponding class.

Comment: I try it, but it is not changed.

Answer (score -1):

The date picker color can be changed by changing the material ui theme. I think it's a duplicate question from [Change header color of Material-UI Date Picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47488211/change-header-color-of-material-ui-date-picker)

```
const muiTheme = getMuiTheme({
  datePicker: {
    selectColor: "#0E6EB8",
  },
});

class Main extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={muiTheme}>
        <TimeInput/>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

For further information about changing material ui theme this is the documentation https://material-ui.com/customization/themes/

Comment: I try it, but it is not changed

Answer (score -2):

Inspect the dial using the developer panel in the browser and see which class is responsible for the color

or

[enter link description here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/6926)

[enter link description here](https://github.com/dmtrKovalenko/material-ui-pickers/issues/393)

Comment: I try it, but it is not changed.

Comment: First try changing the color in the developer tools. Or add !important property to your css code