# Style Material UI InputBase with Date & Time pickers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, material-design

I am trying to style one of the options for date time pickers found in material ui. I made a styled Input I liked, and was trying to use that as a base. Adding the `type="datetime-local"` prop to the component adds the functionality I need, but I can't find a way to style the icon button and the dialog.

Here is my experiment in code sandbox:

The code for the component looks like this:

```
<Paper component="form" className={classes.paper} elevation={0}>
  <InputBase
    className={classes.input}
    type="datetime-local"
    defaultValue="2017-05-24T10:30"
  />
</Paper>
```

The classNames provide the styling I like for the component:
[image]

[image]

But I need to change the color for the calendar icon on the right and if possible the style of the date picker for a dark theme.

How can I do that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ciao, unfortunately you cannot change icon color (to white if I understood correctly). I tried to override `&.MuiInputBase-input` css class also but the only thing I achieved was change text color.

But you can do something more (if you want). You can use `DatePicker` from `@material-ui/pickers`. This is of course more customizable (and I think more cool).

What do you need?

1. @date-io/moment (1.x version pay attention on this);
2. @material-ui/pickers;
3. @date-io/moment;
4. moment;

Installed this libraries you can do something like that:

1. Define a Theme:

   ```
   const Theme = {
     palette: {
       primary: {  // primary color
       contrastText: "#FFFFFF",
       dark: "#000000",  
       main: "#000000",  // black
       light: "#000000"
     }
   }
   };
   ```
2. Create a Mui theme:

   ```
   const theme = createMuiTheme(Theme);
   ```
3. Use a `DatePicker`:

   ```
    <DatePicker
        format={"DD-MM-YYYY"}  // your date format
        label="my date"
        inputVariant="outlined" // if you want an outlined date input
        helperText=""
        size="small"
        value={myDate}
        onChange={setmyDate}
      />
   ```
4. Wrap `DatePicker` into a `ThemeProvider` (to pass `Theme` to `DatePicker`) and into a `MuiPickersUtilsProvider` (to manage date with `moment`):

   ```
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={MomentUtils}>
        <div className="App">
          <DatePicker
            format={"DD-MM-YYYY"}
            label="my date"
            inputVariant="outlined"
            helperText=""
            size="small"
            value={myDate}
            onChange={setmyDate}
          />
        </div>
      </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
    </ThemeProvider>
   ```

And now if you click on date input you got this:

[image]

A DatePicker with a dark style. This is a date picker dialog but you can also have a date picker inline (using `KeyboardDatePicker`).

[Here](https://material-ui.com/components/pickers/) you can find all the date picker versions provided by MaterialUI.

I know, it's a little bit tricky the first time (how many stuff I have to do for a simple date picker!!!) but the result is graphically more beautiful.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-counter-demo-forked-30k8d?file=/src/index.js) a codesandbox example of `DatePicker`.

Comment: Man, how I regret choosing material UI... Anyway, thanks for taking the time. I tried a couple of things with the `KeyboardDatePicker` but wasn't able to style the textfield. And I liked the mask in the native picker much more, since it doesn't let you input wrong data. I'm gonna keep fighting the KeyboardDatePicker. Thanks

Comment: No problem. Yes, material ui is not an easy library but since I have been used it, users stop to say "yes it works but graphics..." Have a good fight (I know you will win) :) :)

Comment: I managed to put something together using the pickers. I lost so much time trying to find a way to style the calendar and clock without using the `themeProvider`, but eventually I gave out. Check it out: [https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-counter-demo-forked-tbc2z?file=/src/index.js:3702-3712]

Answer (score 4):

Fortunately, you CAN change the icon.

It's a platform native element, so you need to reference the underlying tag.

```
input[type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
  filter: invert(1);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I think this has to be the accepted answer.