# How to change color of month/year label of material-ui datepicker in react using createMuiTheme?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to change the color of the label circled here:

[image]

How would I go about doing so?
I have tried changing the color of the primary colors on the palette. Also, there does not seem to be a way to do it through CSS without affecting other components.

Here's my current code for the theme:

```
const calendarTheme = createMuiTheme({
    overrides: {
        MuiPickersDay: {
            day: {
                color: "#436E70",
            },
            daySelected: {
                backgroundColor: "#436E70",
            },
            dayDisabled: {
                color: "#436E70",
            },
            current: {
                color: "#436E70",
            },
        },
    },
});
```

Material-UI pickers v3.3.10
https://material-ui-pickers.dev/guides/css-overrides
Variant: static
Npm package used: @material-ui/pickers

Someone suggested this post: [Change header color of Material-UI Date Picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47488211/change-header-color-of-material-ui-date-picker)

That solution is 5+ years old already,getMuiTheme is not part of v3.3.10. Also the way described in that post does not work anymore, it does not matter where in the createMuiTheme object I put

```
datePicker: {
      color: palette.primary1Color,
      textColor: palette.alternateTextColor,
      calendarTextColor: palette.textColor,
      selectColor: palette.primary2Color,
      selectTextColor: palette.alternateTextColor,
      calendarYearBackgroundColor: palette.canvasColor,
      headerColor: palette.pickerHeaderColor || palette.primary1Color,
    },
```

It does not work, it doesn't have any effects. And the [documentation](https://material-ui-pickers.dev/guides/css-overrides) also doesn't bring much light to the case.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change header color of Material-UI Date Picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47488211/change-header-color-of-material-ui-date-picker)

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47488211/change-header-color-of-material-ui-date-picker

Comment: Could you please provide information about what you are using? Specifically:

 1. version of Material-UI,
 2. source of DatePicker (e.g. [Material-UI Pickers](https://material-ui-pickers.dev/), Material-UI core, MUI X),
 3. type of DatePicker (e.g. StaticDatePicker, DateTimePicker), and if applicable
 4. version of DatePicker.

In any case you will need to look up the documentation (at the appropriate version) to see what **Rule names** and **Global class names** apply to the Pickers components you are using.

If you can send more information, I might be able to provide some help.

Comment: @Shiladitya that solution does not work anymore, it's over half a decade old, getMuiTheme is no longer part of Material-UI pickers package.

Comment: Hey @kofeigen I updated the post, it's Material-UI Pickers v3.3.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation from your link](https://material-ui-pickers.dev/guides/css-overrides) the datepicker has a *rule* (sometimes called *slot*) called **MuiPickersCalendarHeader**. This rule is used to provide styling to a `<div>` tag that is an ancestor to the `<p>` tag that contains the text you've circled in your sample image (i.e. "July 2022"). You can see how these tags are structured in the Inspector tab of the Developer Tools Window in Firefox (in the browser highlight the text "July 2022", right-click the highlighted text, then from the context menu choose *Inspect*). Knowing the tag structure, we can apply a CSS selector to target the `<p>` tag like so:

```js
const calendarTheme = createMuiTheme({
    overrides: {
        MuiPickersDay: {
            ...

            // MuiPickersCalendarHeader rule 
            MuiPickersCalendarHeader: {
                switchHeader: {
                    ['& > div > p']: {
                        // backgroundColor: lightBlue.A200,
                        // color: "white",
                    },
                },
            },

            ...
        }
    }
```

The above code is untested. If you have problems with it say so in a comment, and I'll try to test it.